# Combine Rows in Access SQL where fields are blank

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, union

I have been looking to combine multiple rows of information into a single row to fill in blank spaces.

```
Id | name | value1 | value2 | value3
1    bob      3                                                              
1    bob                        6
1    bob               B
```

How do I get those 3 rows into a single row? It is a confirmed that they will fit perfectly where the blank values are, no values will overlap.

```
Id | name | value1 | value2 | value3
1    bob      3        B        6
```

I have come across nothing of much use in my research besides something called ConcatRelated which I could not modify to fit my needs. I also tried a group by statement which I couldn't get to work either. Any ideas? I am newer to Access and SQL in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get those 3 rows into a single row?

Use a `GROUP BY` query to consolidate the 3 *"bob"* rows into one.  And then you can include an aggregate function such as `Max()` to retrieve the non-blank rows for each of the *valueX* columns.

```sql
SELECT
    y.Id,
    y.name,
    Max(y.value1) AS MaxOfvalue1,
    Max(y.value2) AS MaxOfvalue2,
    Max(y.value3) AS MaxOfvalue3
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY
    y.Id,
    y.name;
```

If you want to reuse the original column name, *valueX*, instead of a *MaxOfvalueX* alias, enclose that name in square brackets ...

```sql
Max(y.value1) AS [value1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that I was using mock data as an example here. The Max() function doesn't really work if the field values contain non-numbers, correct? Like if value2 was a 'B' instead of a number. Maybe I am wrong though.

Comment: You are correct, I wrote it wrong at first. Thank you.